# Hardware reset of Wireless?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm having a serious issue with my wifi. It randomly dies ALL THE TIME, and when it does the only thing that can seem to get it to work again is to completely reboot my computer (pretty annoying).

I think if I could reset it in hardware, it would do the trick -- but nothing seems to be working. I tried the solutions given by the below links -- no luck.

[Resetting wireless connection via command line [SOLVED]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1829796)

[How do I reset the network adapter using a terminal command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54710/how-do-i-reset-the-network-adapterusingaterminalcommand)

Result of doing sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth2
       version: 01
       serial: dc:85:de:56:bb:37
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=192.168.2.137 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 10
       serial: 74:d0:2b:4c:40:6d
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx firmware=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:44 memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

Comment: Please run the command: sudo lshw -C network and tell us what the wireless driver is by editing your question.

Comment: To be honest, it is often easier and faster to purchase a wireless usb. You can get a linux compatible usb wireless card often for $10 or less, and the usb will work on multiple installs. If that fails, identify your hardware and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

To prefer the need to reset your network, suggest you:
Shutdown, disconnect power, open the case and remove then reseat the card.